# jQuery AJAX loading page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to rebuild my site, so that it uses AJAX to load data content inside a div.
This is the function, that handles the loading:

```
navigate = function(url, title, callback){
    //show message to user
    toastr.info('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i> Page is being loaded, please wait.');

    //default variables set
    title = title || url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).replace(/_/g, ' ').capitalize();
    callback = callback || function(){};

    //load content to wrapper
    $("#content-wrapper").load(url + "?" + $.param({page_load: true}), function(res, status, jqXHR){
        toastr.clear(); //hides message
        if(status === "error")
        {
            toastr.error('Page couldn\'t be loaded. Please try again later or contact your system administrator', jqXHR.status + ": " + jqXHR.statusText);
        }
        else if(status === "success")
        {
            History.pushState({page: url}, title + " | PCexpres manager", url);
        }

        //remove modals from inside the content and move them to the end of body - prevents problems with backdrop
        $('body > .modal').remove();
        $('.modal').each(function(){
                $(this).clone(true, true).appendTo("body");
                $(this).remove();
        })

        //execute custom callback
        callback(res, status, jqXHR);
    })
}
```

The problem is, that the content, which is being loaded, often (usually) contains more JS (libraries as well as script tags with my code), which is usually not executed correctly. Example of such response:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pce.local/assets/js/plugins/datatables/datatables.js?1434971835"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pce.local/assets/js/plugins/datatables/extensions/ColReorder/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js?1434972105"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://pce.local/assets/css/plugins/datatables/datatables.css?1434971143" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('.table').dataTable({
            dom: 'Rlfrtip',
            stateSave: true,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            searchHighlight: true,
            ajax: "http://pce.local/technician/customers/index_processing.json",
            columns: [{
                data: "checkbox",
                name: "return 'id'"
            }, {
                data: "id",
                name: "return 'id'"
            }, {
                data: "last_name",
                name: "return 'last_name'"
            }, {
                data: "first_name",
                name: "return 'first_name'"
            }, {
                data: null,
                render: function(customer) {
                    return customer.address + (((customer.address_city !== "" || customer.address_zip !== "") && (customer.address !== "")) ? ", " : "") + customer.address_zip + " " + customer.address_city;
                },
                name: "return 'first_name'"
            }, {
                data: "email",
                name: "return 'email'"
            }, {
                data: "phone1",
                name: "return 'phone1'"
            }, {
                data: "actions",
                name: "return 'id'"
            }],
            stateSave: true,
            order: [
                [1, "desc"]
            ],
            aoColumnDefs: [{
                'bSortable': false,
                'aTargets': [0, -1]
            }],
            iDisplayLength: 50,
            language: {
                lengthMenu: "Display <select><option value='25'>25</option><option value='50'>50</option><option value='100'>100</option><option value='200'>200</option><option value='500'>500</option></select> records per page"
            }
        });

        $(".check_all").change(function() {
            $(".content_wrapper :checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"))
        })
        $("#delete_checked").click(function() {
            var ids = '';
            $(".delete_one:checked").each(function() {
                    ids += $(this).attr('data-id') + ',';
                })
                //remove last comma
            ids.slice(0, -1)

            if (confirm('Are you sure?'))
                window.location.href = "http://pce.local/technician/customers/delete/" + ids
        })
        $(document).on('click', '.delete_customer', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $me = $(this);
            bootbox.dialog({
                title: "Delete customer?",
                message: "Are you sure, you want to delete this customer?",
                buttons: {
                    nope: {
                        label: "No",
                        className: "btn-default",
                        callback: function() {
                            toastr.success('Deletion cancelled');
                        }
                    },
                    yep: {
                        label: "Yes",
                        className: "btn-warning",
                        callback: function() {
                            window.location.href = $me.attr('href');
                        }
                    },
                    yeah: {
                        label: "Yes, delete data as well",
                        className: "btn-danger",
                        callback: function() {
                            window.location.href = $me.attr('href') + '/1';
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
<div class="content_wrapper">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="http://pce.local/technician/customers/add">+</a>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover pce-list_table">
        <thead>
            <th>
                <input class="check_all" name="check_all" value="1" type="checkbox" id="form_check_all" />
            </th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <th>
                <input class="check_all" name="check_all" value="1" type="checkbox" id="form_check_all" />
            </th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="delete_checked" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-nosubmit="data-nosubmit" name="delete_checked">Delete checked</button>
</div>
```

Is there any proper way to load such content and execute the js as if it was a normal page load?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to execute javascript after ajax response is added to the container

```
var arr = document.getElementById('myDiv').getElementsByTagName('script')
for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
{
   eval(arr[n].innerHTML)//run script inside div
}
```

Comment: doesn't help. it seems, that the .load() function executes the js, but maybe in a different order. for example, when using dataTables they load fine and work fine, but some events are not executed. also with fileupload jquery plugin I get this error: `cannot call methods on fileupload prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'`. I do initialiaze the fileupload plugin and the error doesn't appear when the page is loaded normally